# Hive multiple insert on the same destination table at the same time

Tags: hive

I am running a java process where 10 different threads are running. These threads will simultaneously insert record after certain interval in a Managed hive table.

My question is "if all 10 Threads send insert query to managed hive table at same time."
Will there be any query timeout? If yes then what is solution.